# Determining joint probability mass function of the sum and difference of random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X,Y$ are i.i.d. $\text{Binom}(n,p)$ random variables, and
let $S=X+Y$ and $T=X-Y$. 
Now I want to compute the joint pmf of $(S,T)$, which by definition should be 
$$P(S=k,T=j)=P(X+Y=k,X-Y=j)$$
where $k=0,1,2,\ldots,2n$ and $j=-n,\ldots,n.$

However, I'm not sure how to write the above in any form I can work with. 
What I mean is, when I've had similar problems in the past I was given something of the form $S'=U$ and $T'=U+V$ for arbitrary i.i.d. r.v.s. $U$ and $V$.
In that case, it's easy to see that 
$$P(S'=k,T'=j)=P(X=k,Y=k-j)=P(X=k)P(Y=k-j)$$
where the last step follows from independence.

One observation is that from $x+y=j$ and $x-y=k$, we can solve for $x=(k+j)/2$ and $y=(k-j)/2$. However, $(k-j)/2$ and $(k+j)$ might not be an integer. So I'm not sure what to do there.

Ultimately, my question is: How can I write the first equation above in a form as to use independence?

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the law of total probability we have

\begin{align}
\mathbf P( S=k , \, T = j) & = \sum_{x=0}^n \mathbf P( S=k , \, T = j \, | \, X = x) \mathbf P(X=x) \\
& = \sum_{x=0}^n \mathbf P( S=k , \, T = j \, | \, X = x) \binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{(n-x)}.
\end{align}

Further, using Bayes formula we can re-write the first term in the right hand side as

\begin{align}
\mathbf P(S=k , \, T=j \, | \, X = x) & = \mathbf P(S = k \, | \, T = j, \, X = x) \mathbf P(T =j \, | X = x)\\
& = \mathbf P(S = k \, | \, T = j, \, X = x) \mathbf P(Y = x - j ) \\
& = \mathbf P(S = k \, | \, T = j, \, X = x) \binom{n}{x-j}p^{x-j}(1-p)^{(n - x +j)}
\end{align}

Finally considering the remaining conditional probability term, we note

\begin{align}
\mathbf P(S=k\,| \, T = j, \, X = x) & = \mathbf P(x + Y = k  \, | \, x-Y = j) \\
& = \mathbf P(Y = k - x \, | \, Y = x - j) \\
& = \mathbf 1_{(k+j)/2}(x),
\end{align}
where I use $\mathbf 1_a(x)$ to denote the function which is equal to $1$ when $x = a$, and is $0$ elsewhere.

Combining these we get the expression

$$\mathbf P(S=k, \, T = j) = \sum_{x=0}^n \mathbf 1_{(k+j)/2}(x) \binom{n}{x} \binom{n}{x-j} p^{2x - j} (1-p)^{2(n-x) +j}.$$

Alternatively, since there can be at most one solution to $x = \frac{k+j}{2}$, we can write

$$\mathbf P(S = k, \, T = j) = 
\begin{cases}
\binom{n}{\frac{k+j}{2}} \binom{n}{\frac{k-j}{2}} p^{k}(1-p)^{2n-k}, & \text{if $ \frac{k+j}{2} \in \mathbf N$,} \\
0 & \text{else.} 
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Since $S\sim\text{Binomial}(2n,p)$ would the first binomial coefficient be $\binom{2n}{(k+j)/2}$ and the last term be $(1-p)^{3n-k}$?

Comment: No, note that I do not rely on $S \sim \text{Bin}(2n,p)$ anywhere. Note that my answer is consistent with that given by @antkum, thought it takes a rather more piecemeal approach to achieving the same ends.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, $S = k, T = j \Leftrightarrow X = {k+j \over 2}, Y = {k - j \over 2}$, so:

$$P(S = k, T = j) = P(X = {k+j \over 2}, Y = {k - j \over 2}) = P(X = {k+j \over 2}) P(Y = {k - j \over 2})$$

where the last equality is due to independence of $X, Y$.  The formula is still valid if $(k+j)$ is odd i.e. if ${k+j \over 2}$ is non-integer -- in this case the probability is zero, because you cannot have two integers with an even sum but an odd difference (or vice versa).  :)